# Password to confirm transaction

Tags: password

I used shape shift to convert bitcoin to ether and received ether in my wallet. I am trying to send it back to shape shift and it is asking me for a password. I don't remember ever setting up a password. I thought there were default accounts in the wallet. Did I just lose a bunch of money?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you lost it along with the password. It is recoverable with the password.

What i am guessing is, your bitcoin wallet might have some password, not the shape shift.

Answer (score 2):

The wallet prompts for a password when you create the account. Did you try passwords that you commonly use? You can attempt to brute-force it using a file of passwords that might work using https://github.com/ryepdx/pyethrecover

Answer (score 0):

For the account to request for password it means you already activated a password, check your email maybe you can be able to retrieve it or try the last password used for the account probably it might work.

If you have activated fingerprint then you can try that as well